# Swift closure parameter with default value nil still returns some value when not passed by the caller?

Tags: ios, swift, closures, bridging-header

In this code:

```
@objc func postToken(completion: (()-> Void)? = nil) {
    someBlock {
        completion?()
    }
}
```

when added as a call using a selector, like so:

```
let tokenIndicatorGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(postToken))
```

the closure is not nil and thus crashes at the `completion?()` line.

the value looks like:

```
completion  (())?   0x00000001049476f8 MyApp`partial apply forwarder for reabstraction thunk helper from @escaping @callee_unowned @convention(block) () -> () to @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () at <compiler-generated>
```

Searching for the error didn't return much so I am looking for some help figuring this out.

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: In a an action method (in your case tap gesture one), the parameters "can't' be really chosen. They are pre-defined: sender, etc. That's why you encounter the issue. I'll have to find the doc about it, but that's the main reason.

Comment: @Larme - the required selector signature for gesture recognizers is covered in the Overview section for [`UIGestureRecognizer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer). If you're dealing with a `UIControl` then look at the overview for `UIControl`.